# SocketSniff equivalent for 64-bit applications

Tags: sniffing, sockets

[SocketSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html) allows you to watch the Windows Sockets (WinSock) activity of the selected process. 
On x64 version of Windows, SocketSniff can only work with 32-bit programs.

Is there any SocketSniff equivalent that works for 64-bit processes ? I prefer it to WireShark because it filters per process, and it intercepts the messages before they even get to the socket (or at least, as they are getting to it)

Comment: Have you found it? if so, share. I think WireShark is ever-green answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Winsock Tracing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-tracing) to capture data. It's system-wide, but lets you see very fine-grained activity. It's labour-intensive and inconvenient to use though.

Sadly, Microsoft Message Analyzer is dead, as is Microsoft Network Monitor. The former would've been ideal for your needs.

What you probably really need is a Wireshark input method that uses the [Windows Filtering Platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page) for capture. I'm not aware of any at this time; WinPCap uses the NDIS intermediate driver API, which has a different set of pros and cons.